# Can Convolution Layers be Assigned Dynamically?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I recently saw [this paper](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wolf/papers/dynconv.pdf) and I am a bit confused on what they are describing and the effectiveness of the architecture. Is it possible for a neural network to change the convolution layers based on the input? Isn't this basically the same as adding another convolution? As well, is this effective or is this a case of combinatorial optimization?